# What are the weight change limits of Alter Self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I know with alter self you can make yourself practically weigh nothing but i was curious if there was a limit to how heavy you could make you character. My theory is you could make yourself as heavy as you wanted but at a certain point you would end up collapsing under your own weight.

Answer (score 1):

Some people might ask whether *alter self* can change your weight at all, given that the text says "change appearance" and not "change form".  But note that this spell is a transmutation spell, not an illusion spell.  The changes produces by transmutations are changes to your form.

Alter Self says: "You can make yourself appear as a member of another race, though none of your statistics change. You also can't appear as a creature of a different size than you."

So, for example, you could change yourself into a dragonborn, which has "average weight" 250lb.  It's not clear in 5e what the upper bound is for a medium size creature.

A DM looking for guidelines on the upper bound for a medium size creature might look at the table for 3.5e, which says that a medium size creature usually weighs "between 60 and 500" pounds.  Obviously this is just a guideline -- and a guideline from a different edition, at that.  Ultimately you will have to let your DM decide.